# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Is there a way to limit the number of reactions each user can add in a certain channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I saw something that would limit a certain number of reactions to a message, but that's not quite what I want. I'm trying to limit the number of reactions **each user can add in a certain channel** (for example, each person would only be allowed three reactions at a time), - not quite sure how to do that. I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a limit for each message on a specific channel or for the all messages of a specific channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm wrong, you can correct me in comments, but as I understand, you want to limit reaction count for each message in a specific channel for each person. You can do this with different ways.

- For the first way, you can get the all reaction users with a nested for loop, then you can check in `on_reaction_add` event that if the person that added new reaction has already for instance 3 reactions on this message.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = user.guild.get_channel(<channel id>)
    if reaction.message.channel == channel:
        users = [user for reaction in reaction.message.reactions for user in await reaction.users().flatten()]
        
        if users.count(user) >= 3:
            await reaction.message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
```

- Or you can do this with another way, without nested loops.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = user.guild.get_channel(<channel id>)
    users = []
    if reaction.message.channel == channel:
        for i in reaction.message.reactions:
            users += await i.users().flatten()

        if users.count(user) >= 3:
            await reaction.message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
```

As far as I know, the second code is more optimized.

Both of these options will block a user from using more than 3 reactions to a single message in a specific channel.

## EDIT

If you want to limit reaction amount for each member for all the messages in a specific channel:

At first, you have to get all the messages of this channel, You can do this by using `discord.TextChannel.history()`. Later, you have to get all the reactions of these messages. After that, you can get the reaction users in a list, then you can check if a user has already used 3 reactions.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = user.guild.get_channel(<channel id>)
    users = []
    if reaction.message.channel == channel:
        for mess in await channel.history(limit=100).flatten():
            for react in mess.reactions:
                users += await react.users().flatten()
    if users.count(user) >= 3:
        await reaction.message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
```

This code will only check the last 100 messages of the channel. You can change this by changing the `limit` parameter. However, it is not very optimized as it loops through all messages and all reactions. So if this channel is a chat channel, this code may cause a delay in your bot.

Comment: Hmm... I tried both of them and nothing happens, no errors either

Comment: Oh wait nvm, thanks this works great. *However*, it's not quite what I meant. I didn't mean that each person should only be allowed three reactions per message, I meant that they should only be allowed 3 reactions in the entire channel

Comment: How many messages are there on this channel? I have an idea but if the channel is just a channel where you can chat, it won't be very optimized.

Comment: Yeah the channel is for chatting

Comment: This code will still work but as I said, it might cause a little bit delay in your bot. But there's no other way that I can think of.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help!!

Comment: Oh sorry I gave the bounty to the wrong answer- started another one that I can give to you in 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `client.event` or `Cog.listener` decorators to listen for specific events. In this case, we'd listen for `on_reaction_add`. On [reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add), if the amount of reactions is greater than a given amount (perhaps stored in a db), it will remove the reaction.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if len(reaction.message.reactions) > reaction_limit:
        await reaction.remove()
```

This will prevent any more reactions from being added once the unique emoji limit, `reaction_limit`, has been reached. This means even reactions on previous reactions that came before the limit was reached will be removed.

In a cog the code will not be too different.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
    if len(reaction.message.reactions) > reaction_limit:
        await reaction.remove()
```

Now, the issue with `on_reaction_add` is that it will not be called if the message is not stored in the cache. `on_raw_reaction_add`, however, will be called regardless of cache state. This will be the better, more viable solution, as it will not be affected by the many resets, shutdowns, and reloads your application will undoubtedly go through during development. Here is how I would implement this:

```py
# this will be done outside of a cog, for brevity.
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    if channel.guild is None:
        return  # this will only happen in the case of DMs.
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    if len(msg.reactions) > reaction_limit:
         await msg.remove_reaction(payload.emoji.id, payload.user_id)
```

Comment: Hmm, whenever the reaction limit is reached, it doesn't remove it. Didn't get any errors either

Comment: I apologize, I left out the `len` in front of the parentheses. Try again using that.

Comment: Strange, still the same result. Am I defining the limit correctly with `reaction_limit = 3`?

Comment: Well, `on_reaction_add` won't listen to a message if it's not in the cache, so if you reset your bot or reload at certain points, it will dump the cache, making it stop listening to that message. `on_raw_reaction_add`, however, will return the raw data, regardless of cache state. I'll amend my answer to include that, as that would be better for the long term viability of the feature.

Comment: @CarterMichaelis Let me know how it works for you, if there are any exceptions, etc. I'll update accordingly. Also, don't forget to import `utils` from discord.

Comment: Mkay, now it gives me this error: `TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'`

Comment: And if this works, wouldn't limit the number of reactions overall instead of for each user?

Comment: That's the direction I was going, I misunderstood until now, thinking that's what you were aiming for. Also, `on_raw_reaction_add` only takes a single positional: `RawReactionActionEvent`, so in your function definition you've written it as `def on_raw_reaction_add(payload, user)`. Remove `user`, and it should work fine.

Comment: Okay, and how would I limit this to each user's reactions instead of overall?

Comment: I would create a variable `user_reactions`, set it equal to `filter(lambda r: r.user.id == payload.user_id, msg.reactions)`, then make the `if len(msg.reactions) > reaction_limit` do `if len(user_reactions) > reaction_limit` instead.

Comment: well make sure to convert `user_reactions` to a list first, you can't run `len` on a `filter` object.